# how to install android studio 3.5.0 for offline use

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, offline

I downloaded android studio 3.5, android gradle plugin and follow this setup guideline by google [link] (https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#download_offline) in order to install android studio for offline use. But the site is providing android gradle plugin 3.5.0-beta01 and android studio is asking for android gradle plugin 3.5.0. I couldn't find android gradle plugin 3.5.0 and I can't connect my computer to internet (very slow). So how can I download all the required components zipped in one file.

Answer (score 1):

I do not configure anything extra for offline work. Just at the time of building the project without the Internet, an error message appears, where I turn on offline mode:
[image: Turn on offline mode]

But you need to remember to turn it off in the settings:
[image: Disabling offline mode.]

Comment: in that case, you have already connected your computer before or you have download the older version of android studio bundle. how to make fresh installation of android studio 3.5.0 completely offline.